# How to paste widget to a specific page

Tags: widgets

I want to paste a review widget form my POS system specific to just my review page on word press, i copied teh widget code from service site where do I paste on WP site

Comment: Would help if you included some code and some information regarding what you have access to.  I'm assuming this is a javascript widget from your POS service, so you'll probably want to find which theme template you want to display it in and perhaps drop the code in there.

Comment: Thanks Tony found it in page editor

Comment: Glad it ended up being something simple.  